# Phrase query in solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot, solr4

I am using Apache Solr with edismax, and I am trying to execute a search for the following two phrases:

"Dividend distribution" amendment "finance act, 2012" section 115

I want to match documents that contain all words but the phrase should be together.

Currently i get a matches with all words but not get the phrase(double quotes words) together

I tried queries like:

```
    for and query:- +"+Dividend+distribution" +amendment +"+finance+act+2012" +section +115
    for or query:- "+Dividend+distribution" amendment +"+finance+act+2012" section 115
```